# getting content uri on activity result not able to get the file path

Tags: android, android-activity

I am picking up the file from the sd card location on activity result it is giving uri .But from that uri i am unable to get the file path can any one help me on this.i used cursor index getting null .

Comment: Probably there is no file path. [That is not how you use a `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html). Beyond that, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this to get the uri path it will work for me:



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        // display it in image view
        if (Gallery) {
            if (data != null && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                // HelperJava help = new HelperJava();


                try {
                    // When an Image is picked
                    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                            && null != data) {
                        // Get the Image from data

                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                        // Get the cursor
                        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                        // Move to first row
                        cursor.moveToFirst();

                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();

                        // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String

                        if (cover_photo) {
                            mImageView_cover.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
                            Hit_Upload_Cover_Image_Service();
                        }

                        if (profile_pic) {
                            Profile_image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));
                            Log.d("Camera_Profile", "camera profile_image");
                            Hit_Upload_Image_Gallery_Service();

                        }


//                        if (Gallery) {
//                            mButton_Uload_Img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                        }


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You haven't picked Image",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        } else if (Camera) {

            if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // successfully captured the image


                    previewCapturedImage();


                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // user cancelled Image capture
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                    // failed to capture image
//                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
//                            "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
//                            .show();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```